# Criterion for vague compactness of signed measures

Tags: functional-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory

Following Bourbaki Integration, Chapter III, §1, Proposition 15:

For simplicity, consider the space $M(E)$ of finite signed measures on a second-countable locally compact space $E$. Denote by $C_c(E)$ the space of continuous functions $f : E \to \mathbb{R}$ with compact support. Set $\mu f := \int f \, d\mu$. On $M(E)$ consider the vague topology defined by the convergence $\mu_n \to \mu$ vaguely in $M(E)$ if and only if $\mu_n f \to \mu f$ for all $f \in C_c(E)$.

For $\mu \in M(E)$ denote by $|\mu|$ the total variation measure of $\mu$ and
for $H \subseteq M(E)$ set $|H| := \{ |\mu| \mid \mu \in H \}$.

By Bourbaki, the following are equivalent:

(i) $H$ is vaguely relatively compact

(ii) for all $K \subseteq E$ compact there is $M_K > 0$ such that $\sup_{\mu \in H} |\mu f| \leq M_K \lVert f \rVert$ for all $f \in C_c(E)$ with $\textrm{supp}(f) \subseteq K$

and then they remark also that this is equivalent to

(iii) for all $K \subseteq E$ compact it holds $\sup_{\mu \in H} |\mu|(K) < \infty$.

In other words, they say that $H$ is vaguely relatively compact if and only if $|H|$ is vaguely relatively compact. They refer to [Chapter 4, §4, No. 6] but I don't see this equivalence with those results. I only see "$\Leftarrow$" which immediately follows from the inequality $|\mu f| \leq |\mu| |f|$:

Assume that $|H|$ is vaguely relatively compact and let $K \subseteq E$. Then by (ii) there is $M_K > 0$ with $\sup_{\nu \in |H|} |\nu f| \leq M_K \lVert f \rVert$ and therefore $\sup_{\mu \in H} |\mu f| \leq \sup_{\mu \in H} |\mu| |f| \leq \sup_{\nu \in |H|} \nu |f| \leq M_K \lVert |f| \rVert = M_K \lVert f \rVert$. I don't see how to prove the other implication "$\Rightarrow$". Note also that the mapping $|.| : M(E) \to M(E)$ is not vaguely continuous.